# Autowiring Thread class in spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, autowired

Is it possible to autowire a Thread class in spring like controller, Service? If yes what annotation shall I use to autowire such a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, I would consider using TaskExecutors instead of directly creating threads.  This way thread lifecycle, pooling etc. is managed through the TaskExecutor.

**See**
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Yes now I can do it easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every `Thread` accepts an implementation of `Runnable` interface in its constructor. Inject all the dependencies in the implementation and then use an `ExecutorService` to run it.